# After navigating back button command is not responding to click

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am trying to learn .NET Maui by building a simple app like the android Contacts app.  I have a main page that has a list of items with a floating button at the bottom to add a new item as shown in the xaml below.  When the user clicks on the imagebutton I navigate to a CreatePage that allows the user to enter the values for each field in an Account object.  I am using the CommunityToolkit.MVVM library to handle the MVVM stuff.

In MainPageViewModel I navigate to the CreatePage using the "Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route)" in the CreateNewAccount method shown in the MainPageViewModel:

This works fine for the first time I navigate to add a new Account.  When I navigate back to the MainPage and try to click the imagebutton again to add another Account the button is non-responsive.  I do not see why it is not handling the button click when I navigated back.  Any thoughts?

This is part of the XAML in MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CollectionView Grid.Row="0"
    Background="Transparent"
    IsGrouped="False"
    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
    ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.EmptyView>
            <StackLayout Padding="12">
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="No Accounts" />
            </StackLayout>
        </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Account">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding AccountName}" 
                        FontSize="Large"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

    <ImageButton
    Grid.Row="0"
    Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"
    Source="add_box_black_48dp.svg"
    Background="Transparent" 
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private IDataContext _context;
    private bool _isBusy;
    private Account _selectedAccount;

    public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }
    public AsyncRelayCommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }
    public AsyncRelayCommand CreateCommand { get; private set; }

    public bool IsBusy { get=>_isBusy; set => SetProperty(ref _isBusy, value); } 
    public Account SelectedAccount { get=>_selectedAccount;  set => SetProperty(ref _selectedAccount, value); }

    public MainPageViewModel(IDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();
        RefreshCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Refresh);
        CreateCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(CreateNewAccount);

        Accounts.Add(new Account { Id = 1, AccountName = "a1", UserName = "a2", Password = "a3" });
    }

    async Task CreateNewAccount()
    {
        var route = $"{nameof(CreatePage)}";
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
    }

    internal async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await Refresh();
    }

    async Task Refresh()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        var accounts = await _context.GetAllAsync();

        if (Accounts.Count > 0)
        {
            Accounts.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var item in accounts)
        {
            Accounts.Add(item);
        }
        IsBusy = false;
    }

}
```

In CreatePageViewModel I create an AsyncRelayCommand as follows and navigate back to the mainpage after the Account is added using "Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..")"

```cs
public AsyncRelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
public CreatePageViewModel(IDataContext dataContext)
{
    _dataContext = dataContext;
    NewAccount = new Account();
    SaveCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(AddAccount);
}

private async Task AddAccount()
{
    var accountFound = await _dataContext.FindByName(NewAccount.AccountName);
    if (accountFound is not null)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Account alreaady exists", "OK");
        return;
    }

    await _dataContext.InsertAccountAsync(NewAccount);
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in VS Output pane, when you click button first time or second time? (You can clear Output pane before clicking, to make it easier to see.) Please show code behind. Most importantly, the `constructor` and (if you have this) override of `OnAppearing`. Somehow the page is in a different state after going back to it. Or (less likely) perhaps the button itself is somehow not ready to be clicked. Did you put a breakpoint on the command method, to be sure it isn't reaching it again?

Comment: Also show `CreateCommand` declaration and lines of code.

Comment: I edited the initial post to include the information you wanted.  There are no errors in the Output Window but I do notice that there are a lot Thread Pool's being started and finishing.  Not sure if these are being created by the Android emulator

Comment: Yes, the command handler is reached the first time from the MainPage but not after navigating back to the MainPage

Comment: As a test, move button to `Grid.Row="1"`. So it doesn't overlap the list. To rule out possibility of an XF bug when the list is re-laid out with the added item.

Comment: Also try to replace ImageButton with Button to see if problem persists.

Comment: I tried Grid.Row="1" and I also replaced the ImageButton with a Button.  Both cases did not work

Comment: If possible could you provide a basic, reproducible project here to us for test (You could upload it to github and attach the repo link here )? Since I used your code it works fine on my side .

Comment: I will try to post a sample on GitHub over the weekend

Comment: Posted project to https://github.com/jfraschilla/MyMauiApp

Comment: Based on my test , I found the same code works on Xamarin but not MAUI , this should be a potential issue , consider raising the issue on github : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

why you await all events?

```
async Task CreateNewAccount()
{
    var route = $"{nameof(CreatePage)}";
    // we won't wait - await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
    _ = Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
}
```

and everything will work